# how can i add data from table 1 to table 2 in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

lately I've been getting into mysql a bit, i have 2 tables and i want to do the following:

Table 1:
| ID | Code | Merk |

Table 2:

| ID | Code | Merken |

My table 2 is filled with data, and has one column named 'Merken'. For now the column is filled with NULLs. Table 2 has a column named 'Code', this column contains lots of codes with characters and integers, I've made them varchars.
My Table 1 is also filled with data, and has a column named 'Merk'.

Now what i want to do is the following:

How can i make it so that when i compare the Code colums from both the tables that I insert a 'Merk' from table 1 into the 'Merken' column from table 2 when the code is a match? How should i structure my sql query with an insert statement?

Comment: I think you may need an UPDATE rather than an insert.https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.) Also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use update using join as below**

```
UPDATE Table_2 T2
    JOIN TABLE_1 T1 ON T2.code=T1.code 
SET T2.Merken = T1.Merk
```

**For general Update join :**

```
UPDATE TABLEA a 
   JOIN TABLEB b ON a.join_colA = b.join_colB  
   SET a.columnToUpdate = [something]
```

Comment: Welcome!! @hoekrand